# How do I open this door in the desert palace?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

So I'm completing the desert palace, have the boss key, as well as one more small key. I'm in the long vertical narrow room to the left of the room with the boss key, but the door to the left is not open. It has one of those mask/faces on it.

I have been all over the dungeon, and this appears to be the only door I cannot pass through. I have not been able to get it to open. I'm almost wondering at this point if it's a bug!

Anyone know how to open the door, or know where I should try going?

I'm also going to try and update with screenshot.

[image: Standing in the desert palace]

Comment: Hi there, I downloaded and reuploaded your picture to the SE imgur servers in case your link ever breaks. It's helpful for us to have images on our servers for longevity purposes. :) It's also slightly more private for you in that regard, as the photo page details provide your name and current location (though I imagine you have no issue with that seeing as you uploaded it there in the first place). In the future, you can upload images either directly from your PC or via a direct link in a supported format.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to upload an image, thanks FAE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get into the room in the center of your screenshot, you have to enter from the other door on the left (on down the left hallway, you're in the right hall).  The door you're trying to enter is actually the exit door to the room so you can't enter that way.  The chest in the room contains a Silver Rupee (100 rupees).

[image: path]

The extra key that you have should allow you to progress further into the dungeon opening the locked door to the leftmost room on the map.

Comment: OMG, you are absolutely correct. I made the (wrong) assumption that I had to progress from left to right, because the left room is multi-level, and that door is open, but I was able to use the sand shovel to get up to the second level. Thanks!